# Proof that if a system of equations has a unique solution, then $ad - bc \neq 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

I'm trying to understand a proof that if a system of equations
\begin{align*}
ax + by &= r \\ 
cx + dy &= s
\end{align*}
has a unique solution, then $ad - bc \neq 0$. The proof, paraphrased, looks like this:

> Let $(x', y')$ be a solution to this system. Then
> \begin{align*}
> ax' + by' &= r \\ 
> cx' + dy' &= s.
> \end{align*}
> So $(x' + 1, y')$ is not a solution, so either
> \begin{align*}
> a(x' + 1) + by' & = ax' + a + by' \neq r \\
> & \text{ or } \\
> c(x' + 1) + dy' &= cx' + c + dy \neq s.
> \end{align*}
> If $a = c = 0$, then these would be satisfy by the solution $(x' + 1, y)$, so we must have either $a \neq 0$ or $c \neq 0$. Without loss of generality, we can assume $a \neq 0$ by swapping the two equations and relabelling, if necessary. Then $(x' - b, y' + a)$ is not a solution either since $a \neq 0$ so $y' + a \neq y'$. But it satisfies the first equation:
> $$
> a(x' - b) + b(y' + a) = ax' - ab + by' + ab = ax' + by' = r.
> $$
> So we must have $c(x' - b) + d(y' + a) \neq s$. But
> \begin{align*}
> c(x' - b) + d(y' + a) &= cx' - bc + dy' + ad \\
> & = (cx' + dy') + (ad - bc) \\
> & = s + (ad - bc). 
> \end{align*}
> So $s + (ad - bc) \neq s$, so $ad - bc \neq 0$.

I'm able to follow every step of the proof, but I'm trying to understand how I would come up with it. I would appreciate any tips on the intuition or even alternative proofs that may be more intuitive.

Comment: Fix the title. Should be if unique solution then $ad-bc \neq 0.$

Comment: The most natural way to get this result is to use the concept of the determinant of a matrix. I can't see any reason to prove it the way you give as it seems very messy. For a proof using matrices see any introductory linear algebra course

Comment: Trying to do this without matrix notation feels like handicapping yourself. I highly recommend reading a bit about linear algebra and Gaussian elimination.

Comment: To add to Fishbane's note, a matrix with non-zero determinant has an inverse matrix.

Comment: If you were to solve this system using elementary techniques you'd obtain $x=(rd - sb)/(a d-bc)$ (the denominator for $y$ is similar). Hence the reason why $ad-bc\neq0$, Go through the "addition" or "elimination" method to make this clear for yourself.

Comment: @Fishbane This problem is presumably given long before the word "matrix" has ever been mentioned. You do it this way because it's elementary algebra, not linear algebra. Are there faster ways? Presumably. But using the word "determinant" to solve this problem will, the way I read it, be entirely unhelpful.

Comment: @Arthur I agree that matrices probably haven't been introduced. However I stand by that fact that this result is best proved using matrices and that the proof given here is messy. If you want to prove it using elementary algebra the other answers give much better approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method seems unnecessarily complex. Your equations imply:
\begin{align*}
adx + bdy &= rd \\ 
bcx + bdy &= bs
\end{align*}
Subtracting:
$$(ad-bc)x=rd-bs$$
If $ad-bc=0$ then we will have either no solutions for $x$ or infinitely many solutions. Therefore unique solutions imply $ad-bc \ne 0$. Similarly for $y$.

Comment: This approach is very helpful. I'm not sure if I'm seeing in what cases we would have either no solutions or infinitely many solutions.

Comment: If $ad-bc=0$ and $rd-bs=0$ then $x$ can have any value. If $ad-bc=0$ and $rd-bs\ne 0$ then there are no solutions.

Answer (score 1):

For a unique solution we need to have two distinct equations (distinct intersecting, parallel lines)for this to happen we require unequal slopes
$$\frac{a}{c} \ne \frac{b}{d} \implies ad-bc \ne 0.$$

Also by Cramer's rule or otherwise we have
$$x=\frac {ar-bs}{ad-bc}, y=\frac{as-cr}{ad-bc}$$ for $x,y$ to be finite we want $ad-bc\ne 0$.

Answer (score 1):

For a geometric intuition, each equation represents a line and lines intersect exactly at one point (i.e. system has exactly one solution) if and only if slopes (i.e. angular coefficients) are different that is for $bd\neq 0$

$$m_1=-\frac{a}{b} \ne -\frac{c}{d}=m_2$$

which  implies the given expression. The special cases can be checked by inspection.

---

[image]